# Kotlin code failing in runtime with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List java.util.stream.Stream.toList()'

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stdlib

I have a code like `stream.toList()`, the file contains import `kotlin.streams.toList`, compilation works w/o issues, but it blows in runtime with the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List java.util.stream.Stream.toList()'`.

It seems like some package `kotlin.streams` clash, but I haven't found anything it should collide with.

BTW, it's being run in Docker.

Comment: Is it happening only in the container or also on your local workstation? Also, you need to provide more info as JDK version, Kotlin version etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue was, that by mistake, I used JDK 17 for building in console before creating the Docker image. I had JDK 11 used in IDE and JRE 11 Docker base image, but the clash happened because of the JDK used for building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* that you are importing `kotlin.streams.toList`? Check all of your source files for any usage of `Stream.toList()` that doesn't have `import kotlin.stream.toList` at the top of the file. Your stack trace should also tell you which file that is (but you may have more than one such file).

The problem is that Java itself has a [Stream.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) method, but this was only introduced in Java 16. From the error message, it looks like your code is using that. But if your Docker container has a version of Java earlier than 16, that method won't be there.

Make sure to import the Kotlin extension function `Stream.toList()`, which will exist under all JVM targets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue was, that by mistake, I used JDK 17 for building in console before creating the Docker image. I had JDK 11 used in IDE and JRE 11 Docker base image, but the clash happened because of the JDK used for building.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, that by mistake, I used JDK 17 for building in console before creating the Docker image. I had JDK 11 used in IDE and JRE 11 Docker base image, but the clash happened because of the newer JDK used for building (which contains colliding [Stream.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList())).